# Prettier Ruby than "!current_user.nil?"?

Tags: ruby

Ok, I'm green, but the following def seems double-negative-y

```
def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?  #the current user is not...um...not
end
```

Since my patient mentor M.Hartl uses it in [his Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-changing_the_layout_links). I gotta believe it's squeaky, but...

wouldn't something that says "the current user is" be cleaner?

```
def signed_in?
  current_user
  current_user.present?
  current_user.any?
  !!current_user
end
```

What's the benefit of the bang?

Comment: Why not just pick the one you like the most of the options you've given? This is ultimately very subjective.

Comment: Thanks for the link edit Andrew. Lazy on my part.

Comment: But would all the options I've given work or is there a really good reason to use the bang / double-negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
current_user          | nil    | false  | true  | ""    | []    | [nil] | [0]  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
current_user          | nil    | false  | true  | ""    | []    | [nil] | [0]
!current_user.nil?    | false  | true   | true  | true  | true  | true  | true
!!current_user        | false  | false  | true  | true  | true  | true  | true
current_user.present? | false  | false  | true  | false | false | true  | true
current_user.any?     | error  | error  | error | error | false | false | true
```

Comment: Thanks @sawa This breakdown is exactly what I needed to see.

Comment: You're missing the case that often trips people up with `any?`: `[nil, false].any? #=> false`.

Answer (score 1):

In that example you don't care who the user is. All you want to know is that a user, *any user*, is signed in. If so, you will show links for signed-in users.

`current_user.nil?` is a boolean. It will be false is a user is signed in. The bang in front inverts it, so `!current_user.nil?` will be true if *any* user is signed in, false otherwise.

Can you think of another equally succinct way to accomplish exactly that, nothing more and nothing less?

Comment: Thanks Diego, I'm in essence asking almost the same question you ended with, is there a _more_ succinct, maybe more _readable_, way to accomplish exactly that without any loopholes left open?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. Any? and present? are not universal, they depend on types. nil? works for every object.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
def signed_in?
  current_user
end
```

if you can stand it being not a boolean returned from the method. If current_user is nil `signed_in?` will evaluate to false when used in an if statement. To check for nil? is not necessary and I guess it is a matter of style.

Or in your calling code you could:

```
if current_user
  # do stuff
end
```

and get rid of the extra method.